# GetStaticProps with Typescript only working as arrow function, not as function declaration

Tags: typescript, next.js

In the [NextJs Docs for GetStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) it is written as a function declaration.
If I try to make this typed, like this:

```
export async function getStaticProps(): GetStaticProps  {

    const db = await openDB();
    const faq = await db.all('SELECT * FROM FAQ ORDER BY createDate DESC');
    return {props: {faq}};

}
```

It won't work, with the compiler telling me

> TS1055: Type 'GetStaticProps' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.

If I, on the other hand, use an arrow-function expression, which should be equivalent, it does work though:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {

    const db = await openDB();
    const faq = await db.all('SELECT * FROM FAQ ORDER BY createDate DESC');
    return {props: {faq}};

}
```

So, am I missing something obvious? Or am I forced to use the arrow-function syntax?

Comment: Based on their documentation for typescript support, we need to  use it with arrow function only it seems, https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#typescript-use-getstaticprops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second code block, you're typing the full `getStaticProps` function - which includes typing its params and return type.

```js
const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => { ... }
//                   ^ This refers to the type of the function - params and return type
```

However, in the first code block only the return type of the `getStaticProps` function is being typed.

```js
async function getStaticProps(): GetStaticProps  { ... }
//                              ^ This refers to the return type of the function only
```

TypeScript will throw the error you're seeing because the `GetStaticProps` type isn't valid for the return type of the function. It's meant to type the function itself.

---

To properly type the function in your first code block the same way it's done using `GetStaticProps`, you can explicitly type the function's parameters and return type.

```js
import type { GetStaticPropsContext, GetStaticPropsResult } from 'next';

type PageProps = {
    faq: any // Type this property as desired
}

export async function getStaticProps(context: GetStaticPropsContext): Promise<GetStaticPropsResult<PageProps>>  {
    // Rest of the code

    return {
        props: { faq }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @juliomalves, this totally works. Never had an idea of GetStaticPropsResult type.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing, or at least I think it's the same idea. This is what I tried:

```js
const getStaticProps = async ()=> {
    const db = await openDB();
    const faq = await db.all('SELECT * FROM FAQ ORDER BY createDate DESC');
    return {props: {faq}};
}
export { getStaticProps }
```