# How to type the getStaticProps function when using getStaticPaths params?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, static-site-generation

I working on the following piece of code:

It's a blogPost dynamic page: `/post/[slug].tsx`

```
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  const allSlugs = await getAllSlugs();;
  return ({
    paths: allSlugs.map((slug) => ({ params: { slug }})),
    fallback: "blocking"
  });
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const slug = context.params.slug;
  const blogPost = getBlogPostFromSlug({slug});
  return ({
    props: {
      blogPost
    }
  });
};
```

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

It seems that the `GetStaticProps` type is generic and can be customized for my types.

[image]

I created those two types to try to customize the `GetStaticProps` type:

```
type ContextParams = {
  slug: string
}

type PageProps = {
  blogPost: null | Types.BlogPost.Item
}
```

Here is what I'm trying:

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<PageProps,ContextParams> = async (context) => {
  const slug = context.params.slug;
  const blogPost = await getBlogPostFromSlug({slug});
  return ({
    props: {
      blogPost
    }
  });
};
```

But it still thinks that `params` might be undefined. Should I just deal with it? From the code above, does it seem like `params` could be undefined? I wasn't expecting that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70917652/3564935

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The types are defined such that the `params` variable must still be `undefined` even when you declare the type for the params `Q`.  From [the types file](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/1797fc50ab6a6059a3d118236dcd9cbf22ef91b8/packages/next/types/index.d.ts):

```
export type GetStaticPropsContext<Q extends ParsedUrlQuery = ParsedUrlQuery> = {
  params?: Q
...
```

So if you want to be safe then you should assume that you might not have `params`.  I would use the `notFound` or `redirect` properties [explained here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation) to handle requests with with missing `params`.  You also want to handle cases where your `async` function `getBlogPostFromSlug` was rejected.

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<PageProps, ContextParams> = async (
  context
) => {
  const slug = context.params?.slug;
  if (slug) {
    try {
      const blogPost = await getBlogPostFromSlug({ slug });
      return {
        props: {
          blogPost
        }
      };
    } catch (error) { }
  }
  return {
    notFound: true
  };
};
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgcQKYwMowIY2AYwAVcALAZwBoV0tcDCoIwy4BfOAM0ZDgCIA7VAA8YvANwBYAFDThkWHHwR%20ZeAHMaOPEVJkAXNUxb6uuAF442MgE9%20%20OAAoAlOYB8iaXEXLVlgDZ%20GH4ArmosFgDavGS8ALqSUl5Q6MFQ-B6JXnBgugbYAUGhZAB0INhgDg5kIWouZu4OSDlQ2CD6iHDVoWxsTk4Unlkc%20X4ARtj4ANYGvKN%20EFPA-Gq8g6wJ69LSMNZgqHAAwsowwjDELW3mGV5dagaqUEtqGwnbu-sAQvNqhBC%20FghBsAACb3GCPZYJLxKfgnWFgiHPaSbGRSHZ7ODEDQMJjha5wOYQH5-GAGfjBAJwAA%20cC%20RN%20qheWykMN8GhgdOJqgAYtxCmorlZbPZGoNbsiDIDMrcEU8Nk4DDiQMAyKgADychkwdz1fHJGCpdIIdhWWnfLVM1FyaDwVnqTR0IiMZgGNBGR045hqrGoT2UQ7HU7nVpkHWWGx2RyDGEnETSOruKXQnzwW5XGOnYrNEMAfmKtyhcGAHEctxcSay4Os%20Ky3hU8EJXPgFmwAHdsMB7RzzSTeRAQPzGp0ar1C7X9Yaa7Xss72hXp1lG1rBgvWCusija%20x8Lh8CRHKgoIwoOW2GtBhO0lP%20BAYNyIMF%20KC4ODgqg1i8gA)